# Comparing two strings finding first and last differences

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have got two strings and i want to find the first and last differences.

**I.E.:**

S1: 'I helped a very nice old lady to cross the road.'

S2: 'I helped an old lady to cross the road.'

**Desired Output(check by words):**

```
[2,4] // 2 for 'a', 4 for 'nice'.
```

Because the differences are: 'I helped `a` `very` `nice` old lady to cross the road.'

**Alternative Desired Output(check by chars):**

```
[10,21] // 10 for space, 20 for 'e'.
```

Because the difference is: 'I helped a`very nice` old lady to cross the road.'

I can use any of them(or a third option), but the performance is an issue, because sometimes i perform this check dozens to hundreds times per sec.

Comment: OK, so what have you tried or looked into?

Comment: What does your function look like?

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shown us code, the best I could do is to advise you to look at some ["String Metric"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric) algorithms. These are proven algorithms used in high performance applications around the world.

I would in particular ask you to shed light up the following algorithms that are some of my favorite. It is quite easy to implement them and Wikipedia has a nice pseudocode for them as well:

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance
3. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith-Waterman_algorithm